# vlock on raspbian wheezy doesn't work properly

Tags: locking, debian, raspberry-pi, debian-based, raspbian

I've set up raspbian "wheezy" (more information [here](http://www.raspbian.org/FrontPage), and image file [here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads)) on my recently arrived raspberry-pi (model B, but with 256MB RAM). Since I plan to use it via SSH from other locations, I was looking for a way to lock the console on the actual machine.

Raspbian is the first unix based OS I am working with, so I'm not really familiar with it, but I think I am looking for something like "vlock".

I installed vlock like this:

```
apt-get install vlock
```

When I now log into my pi via SSH from my Windows PC vlock works just fine, but when I try using it on the machine itself it shows a strange behaviour.
If I enter a wrong password, I get the usual message:

```
vlock: Authentication failure
```

but immediately after that the commandline shows up as if I entered the right one. So basically everyone can just roll his or her head over my keyboard to unlock my pi.

Does anyone know if this is a known bug (or even intended)? Or are there any equivalents to vlock that I could try?

Thanks in advance.

PS: This is my first question on stackoverflow so I hope I provided enough information. If I didn't, feel free to comment/ask.